# get the index position from the number (reverse working)

Tags: pandas, dataframe

"stock[20] = 25.60"

If I know the index position 20 I can get 25.60
now I know 25.60 but I do not know its index position. I want to know about index position from the information 25.60

Thank you

I was not able to come to any solution.

Answer (score 0):

If need label or position if default RangeIndex use

```
stock = pd.Series([25.6, 10], index=[20,21])
        
idx = stock.index[stock == 25.60]         
print (idx)
Int64Index([20], dtype='int64')

print (next(iter(idx)))
20
```

For position for any index compare helper array, match first value, so position is `0`:

```
idx = np.arange(len(stock))[stock == 25.60]
print (idx)
[0]

print (next(iter(idx)))
0
```

Because compare floats there should be problem with accuracy, so possible use [`numpy.isclose`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html):

```
stock = pd.Series([25.6000001, 10], index=[20,21])
        
idx = stock.index[stock == 25.60]         
print (idx)
Int64Index([], dtype='int64')
```

---

```
idx = stock.index[np.isclose(stock, 25.60)]
print (idx)
Int64Index([20], dtype='int64')

idx = np.arange(len(stock))[np.isclose(stock, 25.60)]
print (idx)
[0]
```